# Can't use JavaScript objects parsed from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am using AngularJS to build a web application.
I have a server running PHP which fetches some data from the SQL-database and encodes it to JSON. On the client side I make use of the Angular $http service to fetch it, parse it and it succeeds, however I am not able to use the variable assigned with the fetched data. 
This is the code to perform the HTTP request:

```
factory.employees = factory.getEmployeesFromServer();

factory.getEmployeesFromServer = function() {
        return $http.get("http://localhost/scrumboard/get_user.php")
            .success(function(response) {
                for(var property in response) {
                    console.log("PROP: "+property);
                    if (response.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                        console.log("Has ownProperty: " + property)
                    }
                }
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
                return response.data;   
            })
            .error(function(response, status, headers, config) {

            })
    }
```

The print of the properties just contains zeroes and ones.
However when the Stringify-print reaches the console it looks like this:

```
[{"email_id":"rob_en@gmail.com","user_name":"rob","first_name":"Robert","last_name":"Allen","password":"roballen","admin_right_id":"2"},{"email_id":"rob_ena@gmail.com","user_name":"robad","first_name":"Roben","last_name":"Lena","password":"aleno","admin_right_id":"1"}]
```

You can see that it is an array out of two objects, but I cannot access these properties of the objects, even though I can use it with an `ng-repeat`. See the following snippet:

```
<li ng-repeat="emp in availableEmployees">
    <label  class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="checkModel" btn-checkbox>
        HELLO {{emp.user_name}}
    </label>
</li>
```

That code produces two list items but no text.

The following image is from the debug console, inspecting `employees` object: 
[image]

I am quite new to web development and hope someone could help me out!
I have done a lot more debugging but dont want to bloat this post no more, so just ask if you need any specific info.

Comment: Have you used the controller. Can you create plunker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to your server is asynchronous. In your factory code you are assigning `employees` to the return value of `$http.get`, which returns [a promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

So in your HTML, you are repeating over the properties of a promise object. Which is why you get that strange output. The console log does however log the correct data, but that data is (like I said) not set to the property you are repeating over.

You should update your factory code to set the result of the promise to the `employees`variable instead of the promise itself:

```
factory.getEmployeesFromServer().then(function(data){
    factory.employees = data;
});

factory.getEmployeesFromServer = function() {
        return $http.get("http://localhost/scrumboard/get_user.php")
            .success(function(response) {
                 for(var property in response) {
                    console.log("PROP: "+property);
                    if (response.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                       console.log("Has ownProperty: " + property)
                    }
                }
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
                    return response.data;

            })
        .error(function(response, status, headers, config) {

        })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be referencing the wrong variable in your ng-repeat line in your view.
I would replace availableEmployees with employees and see if that fixes it as that is what it you appear to be assigning to your scope.

```
<li ng-repeat="emp in employees">
<label  class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="checkModel" btn-checkbox>
    HELLO {{emp.user_name}}
</label>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem on your code is that `factory.getEmployeesFromServer` will not return the list of employees, it's asynchronous. what you can do, is to return only the promise from the factory, like this :

```
factory.getEmployeesFromServer = function() {
        return $http.get("http://localhost/scrumboard/get_user.php");
};
```

then to get the list of your employers, you need to pass a call back to the `success` method, this call back should assign the values you need on a model (let's say `emp`) which should be on your controller `$scope` (`$scope.emp`), like this:

```
promise = factory.getEmployeesFromServer();
promise.success(function(response) {
    $scope.emp = response.data;
});
```